# Menu items are not shown in SherlockFragmentActivity with tabs

Tags: menu, actionbarsherlock, android

My application runs on Gingerbread. It can properly show action-bar menu-item in normal `SherlockFragmentActivity` but when I add a menu item in an `Activity` with tabs the item is not shown. I was expecting to see the item above the tabs on the right of the name.

Is that normal or I'm doing something wrong?

I can add normal options-menu item that are properly show in the menu.

So the main question is: did someone manage to show both the tabs and the action-bar?

Comment: Just add the xml code where you're creating menu.

Comment: I'm not using xml. I'm adding the items programmatically by using menu.add. I pass SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS

Comment: Ok, and have you tried to run you app under ICS? Was everything as you expected?

Comment: Did you remember to set this? `actionBar.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );`

Comment: The same problem on HTC sense ver 3.6 (ICS 4.0.3)

Comment: @JasonRobinson yes I did and the tabs are shown and they work well

Comment: Have a look on it. https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java

Comment: @mike there are no menu item in that example

Comment: Posting your code will help. I'm able to show both tabs and the action bar on my apps.

Comment: ok I managed to make it working now. Your comment is the answer to my question (although it arrived when I had just fix the issue :-) ). If you put your last comment in an answer I will add a comment on how I managed to fix my issue and I will set it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: @herschel me or Mike? Also, which comment?

Comment: sorry I meant you. I meant that the answer is that it is possible. I made it working too. The only thing I needed to do was to add the item in PrepareOptionsMenu and not in CreateOptionsMenu. Honestly I do not know why yet. I do not need to change the menu at run time so I thought it was not necessary to override PrepareOptionsMenu.

Comment: @herschel so you found your answer? Either add answer and mark it or delete post.

Comment: I wasted my 4 days in tracking the f#cking problem. It works by adding  menu items in PrepareOptionsMenu  ...THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing something wrong. Including other menu options doesn't have any issue. If you're using the actionbar spinner, then it's a different case as that wont work with tabs.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the item in PrepareOptionsMenu in place of CreateOptionsMenu
I hope this will work